# a Python script to format plain text to markdown title

Tags: python

I wrote a Python script to format plain text to markdown title.

for example, modify multiple lines

```
['1 Introduction\n',
 'Part I: Applied Math and Machine Learning Basics\n',
 '2 Linear Algebra\n',
 '3 Probability and Information Theory\n',
 '10 Sequence Modeling: Recurrent and Recursive Nets\n',
 '11 Practical Methodology']
```

to

```
['# chapter1: Introduction\n',
 'Part I: Applied Math and Machine Learning Basics\n',
 '# chapter2: Linear Algebra\n',
 '# chapter3: Probability and Information Theory\n',
 '# chapter10: Sequence Modeling: Recurrent and Recursive Nets\n',
 '# chapter11: Practical Methodology']
```

each chapter title in original file starts with only a number, modify them from 1 to "# chapter 1:", namely, insert "# chapter " before the number, append a colon ":" behind the number; finally write the new toc to a file.

here is the code

```
import re
# f_name = 'data_multi_lines_3.md'
f_name = 'data_multi_lines.txt'
with open(f_name) as f:
    line_list = f.readlines()
res_list = []
for line in line_list:
    res_list.append(re.sub(r'^(\d{1,2})( +.*?)', r'# chapter\1:\2', line))
with open('your_file.md', 'w') as f:
    for item in res_list:
        f.write("%s" % item)
```

Is there a better approach to do this?

I guess I should be concerned about the for loop although I have no idea how to improve that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## iterator

There is no need for the intermediate list, just iterate over the text file line per line, and write the parsed line to the output file

## variable name

`f_name` those 3 characters will not make writing or executing the code any slower, but writing it in full can help you understand the code later one

## `re.compile`

You can compile the regular expression

For extra points, you can also name the groups:

```
re_pattern_chapter = re.compile(r"^(?P<chapter>\d{1,2})(?P<text> +.*?)")
re_pattern_out = r"# chapter(?P=chapter):(?P=text)"
```

---

```
import re

file_name_in = "data_multi_lines.txt"
file_name_out = "your_file.md"

re_pattern_chapter = re.compile(r"^(?P<chapter>\d{1,2})(?P<text> +.*?)")
re_pattern_out = r"# chapter(?P=chapter):(?P=text)"

with open(file_name_in, "r") as file_in, open(file_name_out, "w") as file_out:
    for line in file_name_in:
        line_parsed = re_pattern_chapter.sub(re_pattern_out, line)
        file_out.write(line_parsed)
```